# Laravel Mail Subject - Undefined method 'subject'.intelephense(1013)

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

Using Laravel Mail System with the following function, there isn't a subject method defined.

```
    $mail_response = Mail::to($user_mail)
    //->subject($mail_subject) //Undefined method 'subject'.intelephense(1013)
    ->send(new \App\Mail\SendQueryMail($query_mail_params));
```

Following code of SendQueryMail.php

```
class SendQueryMail extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details;
    public function __construct($details){
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    public function build() {
        return $this->markdown('emails.user.send-query-mail');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the subject method in the `SendQueryMail` file.

```
return $this->subject('My Mail Subject')->markdown('emails.user.send-query-mail');
```